# ERROR while creating function- Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run my query but return error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Required suggestions in terms of modification of the query?

```
CREATE function [dbo].[GET_BC_SME_BO_FOR_DR_TEST](@bc_sme_bo VARCHAR(100),@activity_name VARCHAR(100),@activity_type varchar(100))
returns table 
return
(
    select 
    CASE WHEN (@activity_name ='BIA') 
    THEN 
        (
        select top 1 IIF(@bc_sme_bo='BC',bc_coordinator_id,''),IIF(@bc_sme_bo='SME',sme_id,''),IIF(@bc_sme_bo='BO',business_owner_id,'')
        from bcm_bia_department
        where bia_id in
            (
                select top 1 bcm_bia_department.bia_id 
                from bcm_bia_department 
                full join bcm_bia_department_history on bcm_bia_department.bia_id = bcm_bia_department_history.bia_id 
                where bcm_bia_department.bia_name=@activity_type or  bcm_bia_department_history.bia_name=@activity_type 
            )
        )
    WHEN (@activity_name ='BCP') 
    THEN 
        (
        select top 1 IIF(@bc_sme_bo='BC',bc_id,''),IIF(@bc_sme_bo='SME',sme,''),IIF(@bc_sme_bo='BO',business_owner_id,'')
        from bcm_bcp
        where bcp_id in
            (
                select top 1 bcm_bcp.bcp_id 
                from bcm_bcp 
                full join bcm_bcp_history on bcm_bcp.bcp_id = bcm_bcp_history.bcp_id 
                where bcm_bcp.bcp_name=@activity_type or  bcm_bcp_history.bcp_name=@activity_type 
            )
        )

    ELSE 0
    END
)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  There may be simpler/more performant ways to write this code.  For example `full join` seems problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write it like this:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[GET_BC_SME_BO_FOR_DR_TEST](@bc_sme_bo VARCHAR(100),@activity_name VARCHAR(100),@activity_type varchar(100))
returns table 
return
(
    SELECT field1, field2, field3 
    FROM (
        select top 1 'BIA' as activity,IIF(@bc_sme_bo='BC',bc_coordinator_id,'') as field1,IIF(@bc_sme_bo='SME',sme_id,'') as field2,IIF(@bc_sme_bo='BO',business_owner_id,'') as field3
        from bcm_bia_department
        where bia_id in
            (
                select top 1 bcm_bia_department.bia_id 
                from bcm_bia_department 
                full join bcm_bia_department_history on bcm_bia_department.bia_id = bcm_bia_department_history.bia_id 
                where bcm_bia_department.bia_name=@activity_type or  bcm_bia_department_history.bia_name=@activity_type 
            )
        UNION ALL 
        select top 1 ,'BCP' as activity,IIF(@bc_sme_bo='BC',bc_id,''),IIF(@bc_sme_bo='SME',sme,''),IIF(@bc_sme_bo='BO',business_owner_id,'')
        from bcm_bcp
        where bcp_id in
            (
                select top 1 bcm_bcp.bcp_id 
                from bcm_bcp 
                full join bcm_bcp_history on bcm_bcp.bcp_id = bcm_bcp_history.bcp_id 
                where bcm_bcp.bcp_name=@activity_type or  bcm_bcp_history.bcp_name=@activity_type 
            )
        WHERE activity = @activity_name
        ) x
    END
)
```